# Duplicate entity on join request with Query Builder

Tags: join, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm using the Laravel's query builder with this syntax :

```
$article = DB::table('users')->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'users.id')->where('article_id', $id)->first();
```

You can see that both articles and users table have an `id` column.
Then in my view I use the query result, and I only get one `id` whereas I need both.

Is there any way to get them ?

I know I could use :

```
->select('articles.id as myFirstId', 'users.id as mySecondId', 'users.name', ...)
```

But there are many columns in this request, and if I can avoid it I'd prefer.

Thanks
Raphaël N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all fields from the table with higher number of fields with `* FROM table` and then pick one by one from the other table, like this:

```
$article = DB::table('users')
            ->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('article_id', $id)
            ->select('articles.*', 'users.id as userId', 'users.name') // Add rest of `users` fields
            ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks it works well. It should have more exemple of that kind in documentation.